# How to generate random numbers to each .txt in write.table

Tags: r, sample, write.table

I have question about how to generate random numbers for each .txt file generated by `write.table` command. I want to write different rows of random numbers to each .txt file.

```
ref_file <- data.frame(id=seq(1:10)) #
```

#### This creates 10 output file with random samples

```
lapply(seq_along(ref_file$id), function(i) write.table(sample(10,replace=F),paste0(ref_file$id[i],'.txt'), quote=FALSE, col.names = FALSE,row.names=FALSE))
```

My question is how to put different number of rows for each .txt file. 
For example `1.txt` contains 3 rows of sample numbers but `10.txt` can contain 6 random sample numbers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just as quick thought, wouldn't it be possible to change `sample(10)` to `sample(sample(10)[1])`? If I understood you correct that would create samples with different lengths between 1 and 10.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for comment. Now just creating one number for each .txt. I need different lengths for each .txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe as stand alone function.

```
writeFiles <- function(n, maxRows=100){
  lapply(1:n,function(x) write.table(sample(sample(maxRows)[1],replace=F),paste(x,'.txt',sep=""), quote=FALSE, col.names = FALSE,row.names=FALSE))
}

writeFiles(3,10)
```

`n` defines the number of files and `maxRows` the maximum number of rows (And the numbers are then a unique subset of random length of `1:maxRows`.

Comment: Work great! Thanks Man!